# How to suppress Open Telemetry logger in Java

Tags: spring-boot, open-telemetry

I am using Open Telemetry in Spring Boot java application and for every request Open Telemetry agent is logging extra log lines which I want to suppress. There are too many logs as client is trying to poll constantly kafka server status. The `io.opentelemetry.exporter.logging: ERROR` seems to have no effect.

```
[opentelemetry.auto.trace 2021-03-30 09:20:12:470 -0700] [http-nio-9090-exec-1] INFO io.opentelemetry.exporter.logging.LoggingSpanExporter - 'PSFPublishAPIController.publish' : 785a452cf9bc6f901374af3c24491fc3 c3b50425ffd5090f INTERNAL [tracer: io.opentelemetry.javaagent.spring-webmvc-3.1:1.0.1] AttributesMap{data={thread.name=http-nio-9090-exec-1, thread.id=44}, capacity=128, totalAddedValues=2}
[opentelemetry.auto.trace 2021-03-30 09:20:12:476 -0700] [http-nio-9090-exec-1] INFO io.opentelemetry.exporter.logging.LoggingSpanExporter - '/sidhpsf/v1/psfpublish' : 785a452cf9bc6f901374af3c24491fc3 a4a3c3581efd9a24 SERVER [tracer: io.opentelemetry.javaagent.tomcat-7.0:1.0.1] AttributesMap{data={http.user_agent=PostmanRuntime/7.26.5, http.flavor=1.1, http.status_code=200, net.peer.port=54971, http.client_ip=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, thread.name=http-nio-9090-exec-1, net.peer.ip=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, http.method=POST, thread.id=44, http.url=http://localhost:9090/sidhpsf/v1/psfpublish}, capacity=128, totalAddedValues=10}
[opentelemetry.auto.trace 2021-03-30 09:20:12:741 -0700] [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO io.opentelemetry.exporter.logging.LoggingSpanExporter - 'Xorg-Data-Sharing-Input-Topic send' : 785a452cf9bc6f901374af3c24491fc3 b1deb386583762f2 PRODUCER [tracer: io.opentelemetry.javaagent.kafka-clients-0.11:1.0.1] AttributesMap{data={messaging.destination_kind=topic, messaging.system=kafka, thread.name=http-nio-9090-exec-1, thread.id=44}, capacity=128, totalAddedValues=5}
```

**Logging configuration in yml:**

```
logging:
  level:
    root: ERROR
    com.org: DEBUG
    org.springframework: INFO
    io.opentelemetry.exporter.logging: ERROR
  pattern:
    console: '%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t,%X{trace_id}-%X{span_id}-%X{trace_flags}] %highlight{%-5level} %c{2.} - %msg%n'
```

**Launcher command:**

```
java -javaagent:/Users/rshar248/Documents/Softwares/opentelemetry-javaagent-all.jar \
-Dotel.resource.attributes=service.name=psf-service \
-Dotel.traces.exporter=logging -Dotel.metrics.exporter=none \
-Dspring.profiles.active=local app.jar
```

Any suggestions how to suppress telemetry internal log lines will be a great help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are just missing the .* at the end.

Following [the official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-levels) on how you can easily change log levels within a Spring Boot application,
you can add the following in your application properties

```
logging.level.io.opentelemetry.exporter.logging.*=OFF
```

or in the launcher command

```
-Dlogging.level.io.opentelemetry.exporter.logging.*=OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing the log level of the OpenTelemetry JavaAgent the command system property `io.opentelemetry.javaagent.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel` can be used at the command line.

E.g. to disable the JavaAgent logging completely you can add the following assignment to your application startup command:

```
-Dio.opentelemetry.javaagent.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=off
```

Comment: +1 because it was what I needed however I don't think this is the same logger as OP's question which was probably why you already had a -1.

Comment: Thanks @SkySpiral7! You may be probably right about the -1 but the title and the question are both generally. Since OP is even stating the JavaAgent command line, disabling the logging by command line as well makes still sense to me.